# Solving this cryptarithmetic program gives infinite results

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

I am doing the EAT+ THAT= APPLE, where each letter represents a different number from 0-9. I need to find all combinations. I was wondering if there is a better way to write it, especially 'if' and 'for'

I've tried writing it like this but it gave me infinite results

```
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {
int count = 0;
int E,A,T,P,L,H;

for (E = 0; E <=9; E++)   
{
    for (A = 0; A <=9; A++)
        for (T = 0; T <=9; T++)
            for (P = 0; P <=9; P++)
                for (L = 0; L <=9; L++)
                    for (H = 0; H <=9; H++)

    if (((E != A) && (E != L) && (E != T)&&(E !=P) &&(E!=L)&&(E!=H) && 
            (T != A) && (T != L) && (T != E) &&(T!=P)&&(T!=L)&&(T!=H)))
    {
        System.out.println("A"+A+"P"+P+"P"+P+"L"+L+"E"+E);

    }
    else count = count +1;    
}
System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

Comment: "each letter represents a different number from 1-10" - are you sure? You're currently using 0-9. I *suspect* it's meant to be 1-9.

Comment: yaa sorry its 0 to 9

Comment: What condition are you checking for in below line: `(((E != A) && (E != L) && (E != T)&&(E !=P) &&(E!=L)&&(E!=H) && 
            (T != A) && (T != L) && (T != E) &&(T!=P)&&(T!=L)&&(T!=H)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When facing such problems it is of great importance to **simplify the problem as much as possible**.

### Let's create a sub problem:

Assume that `THAT` must equal 8208. What are the values of each character?

You can **notice that you are just solving an equation**:
`T` * 1000 + `H` * 100 + `A` * 10 + `T` = 8208
(The only solution is `T` = 8, `H` = 2, `A` = 0)

### Back to our main problem:

Using the logic above **simplify the main problem to an equation**,

`EAT` + `THAT`= `APPLE` => `EAT` + `THAT` - `APPLE` = 0;

That in fact means:

`E` * 100 + `A` * 10 + `T` + `T` * 1000 + `H` * 100 + `A` * 10 + `T` - `A` * 10000 - `P` * 1000 - `P` * 1000 - `L` * 10 - `E` = 0

**After simplification you get:
-9980 * `A` - 1100 * `P` + 1002 * `T` + 100 * `H` + 99 * `E` - 10 * `L` = 0**

As the values for each variable are very limited we are free to brute force the solution.

```java
public class MyClass {
   public static int[] calc(){
      for(int A = 0; A < 10; A++){
          for(int P = 0; P < 10; P++){
              for(int T = 0; T < 10; T++){
                  for(int H = 0; H < 10; H++){
                      for(int E = 0; E < 10; E++){
                          for(int L = 0; L < 10; L++){
                              if(A!=P && A != T && A != H && A != E && A != L && P != T && P != H && P != E && P != L && T != H && T != E && T != L && H != E && H != L && E != L){
                                 //In your code you are lacking this statment, it checks whether values are indeed a solution of the equation
                                 if(-9980 * A - 1100 * P + 1002 * T + 100 * H + 99 * E - 10 * L == 0){
                                     int[] outArr = {A, P, T, H, E, L};
                                     return outArr;
                                 }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
           }
       }
       return null;
   }
    
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     int[] answer = calc();
     System.out.println("A" + answer[0] + " P" + answer[1] + " P" + answer[1] + " L" + answer[5] + " E" + answer[4]);
   }
}
```

**If you don't want your if statement to be this massive**, you can always create an array of size 10 filled with zeroes and for each variable (let's call it `i`) increase the value for the given index with `array[i]++;`, if at any point at any index `array[x]` > 1 you will know that values repeat.

There are ways of optimizing how the script works, by acknowledging the relations between digits *(for example you can observe that `A` can only equal either 0 or 1, whereas 0 leads up to a contradictory equation, so `A` must equal 1 and so on and so forth until you find the exact value for each digit just by using logic)*, but in the end you will end up with purely mathematical solution and I don't think that's what you want to end up with.

Comment: i was also expecting same ... great

Comment: Hey how can we assume that `THAT` equal to 8208... Any reason

Comment: That's just a separate example to help you visualize how everything works. It could've been any other word and number.

Comment: Can you give me any reference website because still i am confusing for this example

Comment: Is there any algorithm for this

Answer (score -1):

```
**Second Version of Code**

public class EatingApple {
 ArrayList<Permutation>  eat = new ArrayList();
static      ArrayList<Permutation> that = new ArrayList();
static     ArrayList<Permutation> apples = new ArrayList();
      
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      EatingApple apples  = new EatingApple();
        apples.makePermutation();
        apples.searchAppleEqualsSum();
        
        
         
        }

  public void searchAppleEqualsSum() 
 {
     for(Permutation eatP : eat)
     {
         int E_eat = (Integer) eatP.getCharacterValue("E");
         int A_eat = (Integer) eatP.getCharacterValue("A");
         int T_eat = (Integer) eatP.getCharacterValue("T");
         for(Permutation thatP : that)
         {
               int T_that = (Integer) thatP.getCharacterValue("T");
               int A_that = (Integer) thatP.getCharacterValue("A");
               if(T_eat == T_that&&A_eat ==A_that)
                    for(Permutation apple : apples)
                    {
                        int A_apple = (Integer) apple.getCharacterValue("A");
                        int E_apple = (Integer) apple.getCharacterValue("E");
                        if(A_apple==E_eat&&E_apple==E_eat)
                        {
                          int  eat_value = Integer.parseInt(eatP.permutationString);
                          int  that_value = Integer.parseInt(thatP.permutationString);
                          int  apple_value = Integer.parseInt(apple.permutationString);
                          if(apple_value == (that_value + eat_value)&&apple_value!=0)
                          {
                              System.out.println("EAT :" + eatP.permutationString);
                              System.out.println("THAT :" + thatP.permutationString);
                              System.out.println("Apple :" + apple.permutationString);
                              System.out.println(".............");
                          }
                        }
                    }
                        
               
                   
         }
           
     }
 }
    public void makePermutation()
    {
          for(int e=0;e<10;e++)
            for(int a=0;a<10;a++)
                for(int t=0;t<10;t++)
                {
                    String permutationString = ""+e+a+t;
                    int value = e+a+t;
                    Permutation eatCombination = new Permutation(permutationString,value);
                    eatCombination.addCharToMap("E", e);
                    eatCombination.addCharToMap("A", a);
                    eatCombination.addCharToMap("T", t);
                    eatCombination.permutationValue=value;
                    
                    
                    eat.add(eatCombination);
                    
                }
          
            for (int t = 0; t < 10; t++)
            for (int h = 0; h < 10; h++) 
                for(int a = 0; a < 10;a++)
                {
                    String permutationString = ""+t+h+a+t;
                    int value = t + h + a + t;
                    
                    Permutation thatCombination = new Permutation(permutationString,value);
                    
                    
                    thatCombination.addCharToMap("T", t);
                    thatCombination.addCharToMap("H", h);
                    thatCombination.addCharToMap("A", a);
                    thatCombination.permutationValue=value;
                    
                    that.add(thatCombination);
                    
                }
            for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
            for (int p = 0; p  < 10; p++) 
                for(int l = 0; l <10;l++)
                    for(int e = 0; e < 10; e++)
                
                {
                    String permutationString = ""+a+p+p+l+e;
                    int value = a+p+p+l+e;
                    
                    
                     Permutation appleCombination = new Permutation(permutationString,value);
                    
                     appleCombination.addCharToMap("A", a);
                    appleCombination.addCharToMap("P", p);
                    appleCombination.addCharToMap("L", l);
                    appleCombination.addCharToMap("E", e);
                   
                    appleCombination.permutationValue=value;
                    
                    apples.add(appleCombination);
                  
                    
                }
        
        
    }
   class Permutation
  {
      String permutationString="";
      int permutationValue =0;
       HashMap wordMap;

        public int getPermuttionValue() {
            return permutationValue;
        }
    Permutation(String pString, int pValue)
    {
        this.wordMap = new HashMap();
        this.permutationString=pString;
        this.permutationValue=pValue;
    }
    public int getCharacterValue(String character)
    {
        if(wordMap.get(character)==null)
            return -1;
        return (Integer) wordMap.get(character);
                
            
    }
    public  void  addCharToMap(String character, int value)
    {
        
            wordMap.put(character, value);
    }
   

  
  }
}
```

Comment: Not getting correct answer. I have added output of code please check it

Comment: please post first 5 combination so i can compare the output of my code, and check whats wrong

Comment: Have you run the code

Comment: Are these options Acceptable:    EAT :005
THAT :5505
Apple :05510

Comment: @SyedAsadManzoor: "each letter represents a different number from 1-10" - you've got the same value for multiple letters, and you're using 0.

Comment: So.. 0 is not acceptable as Character Value ... and all letters must have different value?

Comment: @SyedAsadManzoor: Sounds like now 0 *is* acceptable. But yes, all the letters must have different values.